# How to have no bugs when multiple instances of a java applet write on the same file on a server

Tags: java, file, concurrency, applet, locking

I have been using Java for a couple of months.

I don't think it should too hard to have an applet write data to a file on a server.

But how do you make sure you have no bugs, when several instance of the same applet, run by different users, simultaneously try too read/write to the same file? Won't that result in a bug?
Is it possible to have a kind of lock that allows only one user to read/write the file at the same time, and have the other instances of the applet wait for the lock to be released?

It's to store high scores from a game on the server - this question is similar to what happens on a wiki, I guess.

Comment: Your question is about concurrency and synchronization. Start e.g. here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/ In the case you described above, You might also want to use some kind of database instead of a plain files.

Comment: *"It should not be too hard too have an applet too write data on a file which is on the server."*  Such a pity then, that it is actually a PITA.  ;)

Comment: What are you using on the server side? If you are using java, you can call a Synchronized method to write on a file from your Servlet. But of course, I'd suggest using database if it's not an overkill

Comment: Thanks for your answer Yohanes. There is nothing on the server side, just an html pages with a java applet inside. I will try to program a servlet to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following design:

Wrap all the logic that reads and writes data to HDD into a static method of a separate class and make this method synchronized. This will cause several threads calling this method to wait, if some other thread has already acquired the lock.

Comment: thanks for the answer...
I could finally solve my problem by spreading the file in subfiles and by writing a php script that runs on the server which handles these subfiles.